# Triggers execution after group update with "in (...)" statement in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have AFTER UPDATE trigger for in table:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[table1] 
   ON  [dbo].[table]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @primaryKey bigint
    SELECT @PrimaryKey = PK FROM Inserted
    if EXISTS(select * from [dbo].[table1] where PK=@PrimaryKey)
    begin
        update [dbo].[table1] set [Action] = 'U' where PK=@PrimaryKey
    end
    else
    begin
        insert into [dbo].[table1] ([PK], [Action], StampIn) 
        values (@PrimaryKey, 'U', GETDATE())
    end
END
```

When I do "update SOME_DB.dbo.TABLE set FIELD='NEW VALUE' where PK in (3,4,5)", I found that only one row was added to the table1 with PK "3". Which means that trigger was executed only once in table.

But I need to have all the rows in table1 with PKs that were updated.

Could you please help me to solve my problem?

Thank you.

Comment: SQL Server triggers are executed once per entire statement, not row-by-row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL triggers use the `inserted` view to identify *all* the rows being inserted.  Your logic is only looking at one of the rows; hence it does not do what you expect.  So:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    update t1
         set [Action] = 'U'
         from table1 t1 join
              inserted i
              on i.primarykey = t1.pk ;
    insert into [dbo].[table1] ([PK], [Action], StampIn) 
       select i.primarykey, 'U', getdate()
       from inserted i
       where not exists (select 1 from dbo.table1 t1 where t1.pk = i.primarykey);
END;
```

You don't actually need the conditional logic, because the `join` and `where` clauses take care of that.